# How to pass information from MYSQL server on Bluehost to my nodeJS app on Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, heroku

I am trying to get an array of questions and answers stored in a MYSQL database (bluehost) for a quiz nodeJS app (heroku). I have tried using a static IP add on, but I am wondering if it is possible to somehow run the MYSQL query, create the array, and simply pass it somehow to the nodeJS app without requesting it remotely from the MYSQL database on heroku. My first thought was to try and do this through PHP somehow? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MySQL can't send HTTP requests to your app, no. You could have a PHP script running via a cron job in your bluehost which could regularly query the data from mysql and send it to nodeJS via HTTP though. It depends exactly how/when you need nodeJS to get the data though, and how it would store it and keeep it updated. What's wrong with simply giving the nodeJS app access to mysql, though?

Comment: On heroku, the IP address is dynamic. So I would need to go through an IP Proxy. This information is not sensitive. I am already sending information through the URL via GET with PHP but I didn't know if this was possible with an array.

Comment: Well you _can_ send array data through GET, but it could be a bit messy. Just use a POST instead.

Comment: That's what I think I'll end up doing...I don't need to modify any information on the server so best to use a POST.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.